# Can I repeat command in irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

Is there an easy way to repeat a previous command in Ruby irb?
I wish to have something like using exclamation mark (!) in Unix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def repeat_last_irb
  eval(IRB.CurrentContext.io.line(-2))
end
```

then you can use `replat_last_irb` in you irb console to run last input.

IRB.CurrentContext.io is like this below:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > def hello
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > IRB.CurrentContext.io
 => #<IRB::ReadlineInputMethod:0x00000001c7b860 @file_name="(line)", @line_no=3, @line=[nil, "def hello\n", "end\n", "IRB.CurrentContext.io\n"], @eof=false, @stdin=#<IO:fd 0>, @stdout=#<IO:fd 1>, @prompt="ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > ">
```

this Object save irb all io info, and with a line method to get every line you input.

so, we can use eval to repeat last input.

Comment: Hi, rather than using offset, I found that we can put the line number that we want to repeat.. thanks! with additional method I can do it easily!

Answer (score 8):

Up arrow gets you history line by line. Pry has more goodies but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Ctrl-r will also reverse search through the history, in both IRB and Pry (I assume it's a general readline feature).

Comment: @d11wtq - I'm getting ctrl-r in 1.8.7 but not 1.9.3 - did we lose it? Or is my irb broken?

Comment: I suspect it has been compiled against a different version of readline. Works fine for me.

Comment: @d11wtq - Thanks. I will have to see if I can get that back.

Comment: @ d11wtq - Found the answer here in case any one is interested(osx specific): http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080313113705760

Comment: good to know, thanks. I have ruby installed on my mac, but almost always work inside a linux VM running under VMWare :)

Answer (score 6):

Aside from pressing up arrow and enter, the [Pry](http://pry.github.com) REPL let's you reply entire expressions (rather than just lines) using the `play -i` command:

see here:

```
[31] (pry) main: 0> (1..5).map do |v|
[31] (pry) main: 0*   v * 2
[31] (pry) main: 0* end  
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[32] (pry) main: 0> play -i 31
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[33] (pry) main: 0>
```

You simply pass to `play -i` the expression number (the number in `[]` adjacent to the prompt) for the code you want to replay.

For more info on the `play` command see the [wiki page](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Special-Locals#wiki-In_and_out) also check out the [Entering input](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/User-Input) for other tricks related to using and manipulating input history

Alternatively, if you want to just replay individual lines of history, you can first view history using the `hist` command and then replay it using `hist --replay` as follows:

```
[37] (pry) main: 0> puts "hello world"
hello world
=> nil
[38] (pry) main: 0> hist --tail
9699: _file_
9700: (1..10).map do |v|
9701: (1..5).map do |v|
9702:   v * 2
9703: end
9704: play -i 31
9705: _
9706: hist --tail
9707: hist -r
9708: puts "hello world"
[39] (pry) main: 0> hist --replay 9708
hello world
=> nil
[41] (pry) main: 0>
```

Alternatively, if you just want to replay the last line input, and you don't want to use `up arrow` (for whatever reason) then simply use: `hist --replay -1`. As always the wiki contains [more info on the hist command](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/History#wiki-Hist_replay).

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way to repeat (or modify) an earlier command that is more than just a couple of steps back in the history, is to search for it by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by some substring of the command in question.

For more keyboard shortcuts provided by the [GNU Readline library](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/), look [here](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts). They are supported by many shells and other applications as well.

Comment: It would be nice, but Ctrl-R isn't supported in `irb`.

Comment: @r_ that is not true. IRB supports Ctrl-R just fine for me (ruby 1.9.3).  I think it's actually a readline feature, so probably depends on your version of libreadline.

Comment: It's been in libreadline for many years, so I'd say it's more a matter of whether Ruby/IRB was compiled with libreadline support. It should be as long as you have libreadline installed when you install/compile Ruby/IRB. Without libreadline you probably won't be able to use arrow keys to navigate the history either.

Comment: Ah, my mistake--I didn't have libreadline when I built Ruby, so I didn't realise I was missing this functionality! Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat related.

In `IRB`, the result of the last executed command is saved in `_`. You can also use that one.

Example

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > 2 + 2
 => 4 
1.9.3p194 :002 > _
 => 4 
1.9.3p194 :003 > _ * 3
 => 12 
1.9.3p194 :004 > _
 => 12
```

This proved to be very useful for me, especially in `rails console`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any kind of numbered history support (such as like `gdb`), but you can use the arrow keys to navigate through history, the same as you can in the shell.

**Update**

Turns out I'm completely wrong, and Hooopo is right; you can access the history via the `IRB.CurrentContext.io.line` method, so

```
eval IRB.CurrentContext.io.line <line number>
```

will repeat the command. As Hooopo also says, wrapping this in a method works correctly:

```
def r(number)
  eval IRB.CurrentContext.io.line number
end
```

then

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :004 > puts "hello"
hello
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :005 > r 004 # (or 'r 4')
hello
 => nil
```

Comment: ya, I see that irb line command has an increasing number, wondering if it's useful to repeat command.

Comment: let's say I want to load this method definition automatically when starting irb, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Your `r 004` will interpret `004` as an octal. Careful with that.

Answer (score 1):

The irb REPL doesn't natively support [history expansion](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html), which is what you seem to be looking for. For a solid alternative, the pry REPL offers the [replay](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/History#wiki-Hist_replay) command.

Answer (score 0):

You can also backtrace commands in irb by starting it with

irb --tracer

Now the up arrow will go back thru the irb commands.
  (Using Ruby 2.3.3)